# Understanding a formula for the solution to an inhomogeneous linear difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, finite-differences

My question comes from section 8.4 of *Analysis of Numerical Methods* by Isaacson and Keller. I am trying to get a better understanding of the formula stated in Theorem 3, p.409. First, some definitions and basic facts:

**Definition 1.** An *$n$th order inhomogeneous linear difference equation* is a system of equations of the form
$$ \hspace{2cm}  \sum_{s=0}^{n} a_s u_{j+s} = c_{j+n}, \quad j = 0,1,2,\ldots \hspace{2cm} (1) $$

Here, the coefficients $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $c_n,c_{n+1},c_{n+2},\ldots$ are complex numbers with $a_n \neq 0$; the sequence $\{u_j\}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ is complex-valued, and is to be determined based on the given coefficients. In the special case where $c_{j+n} = 0 $ for all $j \geq 0$, i.e. when
$$ \hspace{2.3cm}  \sum_{s=0}^{n} a_s u_{j+s} = 0, \quad j = 0,1,2,\ldots \hspace{2.3cm} (2) $$

the system is called *homogeneous.*

**Proposition 1.** The set of all complex-valued sequences $\{u_j \}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ satisfying the homogeneous equation (2) forms an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

**Definition 2.** A basis for the solution space of (2) is called a *fundamental set of solutions.*

**Proposition 2.** For each $(v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{C}^n$, the homogeneous initial value problem
$$
      \hspace{1.8cm}
      \begin{cases}        
           \displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{n} a_s u_{j+s} = 0, \quad j = 0,1,2,\ldots  \\[5pt]
           u_0 = v_0, \; u_1 = v_1, \ldots, u_{n-1} = v_{n-1}
      \end{cases}
       \hspace{1.8cm} (3)
$$
has a unique solution.

Now here is the theorem which I am trying to better understand. I am also including the author's preceding paragraph because I think it is useful:

> Let us now consider the inhomogeneous $n$th order linear difference equations (1). If $\{v_j\}$ is any particular solution of equation (1) and $\{u_j\}$ is a solution of the homogeneous system (2), then $\{u_j + v_j\}$ is a solution of (1). This solution of (1) can be made to satisfy any particular initial conditions by adjusting the $\{u_j\}$. We now develop a discrete analog of what is known as *Duhamel's principle* in the theory of differential equations (where integral representations of solutions are obtained).
>
> **Theorem 3.** Let $\{u_j^{(0)}\}_{j=0}^{\infty}, \ldots, \{u_j^{(n-1)}\}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ be the fundamental set of solutions of the $n$th order homogeneous difference equation (2) that satisfy the initial conditions
> $$ \hspace{2.2cm} u_i^{(k)} = \delta_{ik}, \quad i = 0,1,\ldots,n-1; \quad k = 0,1,\ldots,n-1. \hspace{2.2cm} (7)   $$
>
> Then the solution of (1) subject to the initial conditions
> $$u_{0} = v_0, \; u_1 = v_1, \; \ldots, \; u_{n-1} = v_{n-1}$$
> is given by
> $$
>   \hspace{2cm}     u_j = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} v_k u_j^{(k)} + \frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{k=0}^{j-n} c_{k+n} u_{j-k-1}^{(n-1)}, \qquad j = 0, 1,2, \ldots  \hspace{2cm} (8)
> $$
> where we define $u_i^{(n-1)} := 0$ for all $i < 0$ and $c_j := 0$ for all $j < n$.

**My question.** How would we obtain the second summation in (8)?

I have gone through the proof and am convinced the formula is correct, but the proof isn't particularly enlightening. I am looking for the *intuition* behind the second summation. This is my current understanding:  By the discussion preceding the theorem, we can express the solution of the IVP as the sum of a particular solution of (1) and a solution of the homogeneous system. The sequence defined by the first summation clearly satisfies the initial conditions $u_i = v_i, \, i =0,1,\ldots,n-1$, and it is clearly a solution of the homogeneous problem (because such solutions are closed under linear combinations). The sequence defined by the second summation, which I'll denote by $\{w_j \}_{j=0}^{\infty}$, satisfies $w_j = 0$ for $j = 0,1,\ldots,n-1$, and (with some algebra) can be shown to satisfy the inhomogeneous equations (1). So the formula works....but how would we intuitively come up with such a sequence $\{w_j\}$?

Comment: I expect the author refers to the intuition behind formula (8) here: "We now develop a discrete analog of what is known as *Duhamel's principle* in the theory of differential equations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind Duhamel's principle is to convert a nonhomogeneous equation with homogeneous initial conditions into a homogeneous equation with non homogeneous initial conditions. I explained the physical interpretation in a previous answer of mine [How to understand the Duhamel's principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4829704/1051191). In short, the inhomogeneous part of the equation is like an external force, that you can decompose in localised impulses by superposition. Each impulse can be seen as causing a discontinuity in the response. If the response has homogeneous initial conditions, it starts from zero. Thus, viewing the discontinuity in the right limit, this amounts to specifying an initial condition at the impulse time.

To solve (1), by superposition with a solution of (3), you reduce to the case of homogeneous initial conditions, this corresponds to the first sum in (8). Next, by superposition, you can assume that $c$ is supported exactly at one index, i.e. you write:
$$
c = \sum_{i=n}^\infty c_i\delta_i
$$
with:
$$
\delta_i=(\delta_{ij})_{j\in\mathbb N}
$$
the sequence that is 1 at $i$ and zero elsewhere. This is the analogue of decomposing the external force into elementary impulses. You then just need to solve (with $D$ the finite difference operator):
$$
Dg^{(i)} = \delta_i
$$
and you can reconstruct the solution as:
$$
u = \sum_{i=n}^\infty c_ig^{(i)}
$$
the sum is well defined because the $g^{(i)}$ are supported on $[i,\infty)$ (by "causality"), so each term of $u$ only involves the summation of a finite number of terms.

Now, to solve for the elementary solutions $g$ (Green's functions), the core of Duhamel's principle is to convert it into the homogeneous equation with suitable initial conditions. Applying (1) to $j=i-n$, the only index where the RHS is non zero, gives:
$$
\sum_{s=0}^na_sg_{i-n+s}^{(i)} = 1
$$
only, for $k<i$ $g^{(i)}_k = 0$ since it is solution to the homogeneous equation with zero initial conditions. The equation thus becomes:
$$
a_n g_i^{(i)} = 1
$$
i.e. $g_j^{(i)}=0$ for $j=i-n+1, ... i-1$ and $g_i^{(i)} = 1/a_n$. After the impulse, $g$ satisfies the homogeneous equation again. To summarize:
$$
\begin{align}
g_{k+i-n+1}^{(i)} &= \frac{\delta_{k,n-1}}{a_n} && k=0 … n-1\\
\sum_{s=0}^na_s g_{j+s+i-n+1}^{(i)}&=0 && j\in\mathbb N
\end{align}
$$
so you recognize the definition of $u^{(n-1)}$ for the subsequence $(g_{k+i-n+1}^{(i)})_{k\in\mathbb N}$. The key property is the shift invariance of the difference equation. The rest if the values are just zero so:
$$
g_j^{(i)} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{a_n}u^{(n-1)}_{j-i+n-1} & j > i-n \\
0 & j < i
\end{cases}
$$
Note the overlap region for $i-n<j<i$ where both give zero. You now have all you need to reconstruct the solution.

Explicitly:
$$
\begin{align}
u_j &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_ku^{(k)}_j+\sum_{i=n}^\infty c_ig_j^{(i)} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_ku^{(k)}_j+\sum_{i=n}^jc_ig_j^{(i)}  && \text{(causality)}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_ku^{(k)}_j+\sum_{i=n}^jc_i\frac{1}{a_n}u^{(n-1)}_{j-i+n-1}\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_ku^{(k)}_j+\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=0}^{j-n}c_{k+n}u^{(n-1)}_{j-k-1} && k = i+n
\end{align}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your your answer.  I haven't seen Duhamel's principle before, so it is taking me some time to digest it...for the "unit impulse" $\delta_i$, is this the sequence $\{0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots\}$ (1 in the $i$th position, zero everywhere else)?

Comment: OK. And in your equation following "Applying (1) to $j  = i - n$", why is the right-hand side 1 instead of $(\delta_i)_{i-n} = \delta_{i,i-n} = 0$?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Ok, I now understand how you got the equation $\sum_{s=0}^{n} a_s g_{i - n + s}^{(i)} = 1$. Then since $g_k^{(i)} = 0$ for all $k < i$, only the $s = n$ term of the summation is nonzero. So shouldn't the summation simplify to $a_n g_i^{(i)} = 1$? I don't understand how you got $a_n g_n^{(i)} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I am trying to understand the last part of your argument. How did you obtain $g_j^{(i)} = \frac{1}{a_n} u_{j - i + n - 1}^{(n-1)}$ for $j > i - n$? I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say "After the impulse, $g$ satisfies the homogeneous solution again". Do you mean that $\sum_{s = 0}^{n} a_s g_{j+s}^{(i)} = 0$ for $j > i$?

Comment: Ok, but I still do not see how $\sum_{s=0}^{n} a_s g_{j+s}^{(i)} = 0$ for $j > i - n$ implies that $g_j^{(i)} = \frac{1}{a_n} u_{j - i + n - 1}^{(n - 1)}$ for $j > i - n$. Would you mind spelling out the details?

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, I think I now understand your argument. However, there is actually a mistake in the indices. We should have $c = \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} c_i \delta_{i-n}$, and so I think the $g^{(i)}$'s should satisfy $Dg^{(i)} = \delta_{i-n}$ for $i \geq n$. Then, if I understand "causality" correctly, I believe this means $g_j^{(i)} = 0$ for $j < i - n$...is this correct? If so, then setting $j = i - n$ would lead to the equation $\sum_{s=0}^{n} a_s g_{i-n+s}^{(i)} = 1$, but I don't see how the sum would simplify to a single term as before...

Comment: Given the mistaken summation for $c$, I do not see how your answer, as it currently stands, is correct...(though I could be misunderstanding something). Any clarification on this would be much appreciated. I am determined to get to the bottom of this problem!

Comment: Checked the indices, I stand by my answer, I believe you’re mistaken. According to your (1), $c$ is supported in indices $j+n$ with $j\in\mathbb N$ you even wrote explicitly the first values. Try it with specific values and you’ll see. I’ll add the final step of reconstruction for completeness

Comment: Thanks for including the final steps; that part makes sense. As for the indices confusion: are you thinking of $c$ as the sequence $(0,0,...,0,c_n,c_{n+1},\ldots)$, with $n$ leading zeros? If so, then I would agree that $c = \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} c_i \delta_i$. I had been thinking of $c$ as the sequence $(c_n,c_{n+1},\ldots)$.

Comment: yes, you need to match the indices of (1). In fact, you can complete it however you want for $i<n$ since these values are not used.

Comment: Got it! That misinterpretation on my part was a big sticking point. Now your solution makes complete sense. Many thanks for patiently answering all of my questions!

Comment: No problem. The general case is not the easiest to apprehend either. To better understand these indices issues, it's always best to check out specific examples like $n=1$.